# Как использовать getCurrentSession в Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Конфигурация

```
      static {
    try {
        Properties prop= new Properties();
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", url);
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", user);
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
        concreteSessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
                .addPackage("Main.*")
                .addProperties(prop)
                .addAnnotatedClass(DeviceDataSet.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}


public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    return concreteSessionFactory;
}
```

Использую

```
    public long insertNewJournalNote(JournalDataSet journalDataSet) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    MySqlDAO dao = new MySqlDAO(session);
    return dao.insertNewJournalNote(journalDataSet);
}
```

При getCurrentSession получаю

```
   Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: No 
   CurrentSessionContext configured!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить

```
prop.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
```